# Toshiba Bluetooth driver installation stalls at 5 bars

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bluetooth, toshiba-laptop, toshiba-stack

I am trying to install my Bluetooth driver after having formatted my laptop but the instillation stalls to these two windows for over 30 minutes and still going on.

- OS: Windows 7 Ultimate x64
- Toshiba Satellite P750-133
- Driver Version - Toshiba PC Bluetooth Stack 8.00.12

  [image: Screenshot of Bluetooth installation hanging at 5 bars]
  [image: The Bluetooth Stack for Windows hanging]

Comment: Can you provide some more Information on the Bluetooth Hardware and used Driver Version...

Comment: @M.Bennett updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I *must* install the  *Bluetooth Filter Driver Package* before installing the *Toshiba PC Bluetooth Stack.*

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem but succeeded by installing the [Bluetooth Filter Driver](http://support1.toshiba-tro.de/tedd-files2/0/bfdp-20110419111708.zip) package first. After the drive was installed version 8 of the Toshiba Bluetooth Stack did not block during the install.